# launching SAS Management Console from a mac over SSH with X11

Tags: macos, unix, sas, x11

I have a remote instance of SAS Management Console in the following location:

> /pub/sas/SASManagementConsole/9.4/sasmc_console

I'd like to be able to launch this as a GUI interface.  I've tried the following (in XQuartz):

```
export DISPLAY=:0
ssh -x myuser@app.myserver.com
cd /pub/sas/SASManagementConsole/9.4
./sasmc_console
```

This returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 
window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

What should be the value of my display variable?

Answer (score 0):

doh..  So it appears I should have used an uppercase X as follows:

```
ssh -X myuser@app.myserver.com
```

But there were other things I had to update before the window worked properly.  First, in the following file:

```
/private/etc/ssh_config
```

I changed the following values:

```
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted no
```

to:

```
#   ForwardX11 yes
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

I also ran:

```
rm /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

And restarted the machine...